# Get interact sliders from jupyter notebook to work in the bokeh html file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, slider, bokeh

Hello this is my first question (iam noob in everything) and iam kind of nervous not to get on your nervouse.

My overall goal is to create a 30 min lesson (part) where pupils can see:

- interactive graphics and the super-fency CODE.

  - get attracted to become software engineers_innen or at least start to read the code. (me Measure the impact)

For this i think Jupyter notebook is the best weapon. For usability reason and different levels of interactivity i started to think about creating html-files to have remote access (my admins will kill me before letting me install sth. more on the school enviroment)

So i saw this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
```

to create a html out of a bokeh figure.

But how to get nice interact sliders to this standalone html-file.

So how to (even if its non-sense) convert this [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.9/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb):

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

In [ ]:

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y = np.sin(x)

In [ ]:

p = figure(title="simple line example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(-5,5))
r = p.line(x, y, color="#2222aa", line_width=3)

In [ ]:

def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    elif f == "tan": func = np.tan
    r.data_source.data['y'] = A * func(w * x + phi)
    push_notebook()

In [ ]:

show(p, notebook_handle=True)

In [ ]:

interact(update, f=["sin", "cos", "tan"], w=(0,100), A=(1,5), phi=(0, 20, 0.1))
```

Into sth. like this: https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders

Thanks for every comment. sry my english is not as good as look like, but iam not as smart as i look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not any straightforward way that I know of to make this work in standalone HTML with *Jupyter interactors*. However, you can make standalone output that accomplishes this with Bokeh's own widgets:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html

There is some ongoing work that should be out with Bokeh 2.0 that will allow Jupyter interactors to work with Bokeh server apps (not standalone output).

Comment: The link is broken as of the time of writing this comment. (Returns 404)

Comment: The gallery has has had to be re-organized to accommodate a sizeable increase in the number of examples in the intervening half-decade. You can can find many widget examples by browsing https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html

Comment: Thank you. None of their interactive examples work. That said, if I rerun the cell that calls `show`, it seems that the interaction works, but the chart does not get refreshed unless the cell is ran again explicitly.

Comment: All of the examples work for me. It's not really clear at all what sequence of steps you are taking or what you are doing (are you using classic notebook? jupyterlab? did you install the jupyter Bokeh extension?) so it's not possible to speculate whether you are seeing an actual problem, or having a usage issue. You might find the Bokeh Discourse a better forum for general new user discussions: https://discourse.bokeh.org/

Comment: I have tried with vscode Jupyter extension. I also tried with installing Jupyter and running it via `jupyter notebook`. It just does not work (interactively without any manual intervention) no matter what I do.

I suspect it might have something to do with the combination of jupyter/bokeh version - but I also am using latest versions of both, so at this stage - I am not investing time in investigating which is the case.

Comment: What is "it"? Some specific notebook? Is it using an embedded Bokeh server app to drive the widgets? Then that can't possibly function without actual cell exectutions. I suppose your expectations here are just off the mark, but without actual details (e.g. the actual code you are using) then you are correct that no investigation can help.